# jquery updating global variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code where I want to play the next song everytime I click on forward. Except he doesn't recognize ii, and throw me an error  TypeError: playlist[ii] is undefined

I've tried window.ii, same error.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
ii = 0


var playlist = [
    {
        'name' : "Ida Maria - Oh My God",
        'src' : "01 Oh My God.m4a",
        'codec' : 'mp4'
    },
    {
        'name' : "Miley Cyrus - Wrecking Ball",
        'src' : "06 Wrecking Ball.mp3",
        'codec' : 'mpeg'
    }
]


  $('.forward').click(function(){
    ii++
    audio.unload()
    audio.urls = mp3_folder + playlist[ii].src
    audio.load()
    audio.play()
  })
```

Comment: you can just change "var playlist=" to "playlist=" so it's a global like your ii is. or use "var" outside the function...

Answer (score 2):

I'd say will tell you that you should **not** add stuff like that in your global
scope. In your case, you do not need to poulate the global scope at all. Keep the scoping minimum.You also had a lot of lexical issues like missing semicolon at the end of lines and closing brackets but try the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var ii = 0;


var playlist = [
    {
        'name' : "Ida Maria - Oh My God",
        'src' : "01 Oh My God.m4a",
        'codec' : 'mp4'
    },
    {
        'name' : "Miley Cyrus - Wrecking Ball",
        'src' : "06 Wrecking Ball.mp3",
        'codec' : 'mpeg'
    }
];


  $('.forward').click(function(){
    ii++;
    audio.unload();
    audio.urls = mp3_folder + playlist[ii].src;
    audio.load();
    audio.play();
  });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try declaring the `playlist` like this:

`window.playlist`

So you'll have

```
window.playlist = [
    {
        'name' : "Ida Maria - Oh My God",
        'src' : "01 Oh My God.m4a",
        'codec' : 'mp4'
    },
    {
        'name' : "Miley Cyrus - Wrecking Ball",
        'src' : "06 Wrecking Ball.mp3",
        'codec' : 'mpeg'
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to move your playlist variable outside of your onload event method.

```
var playlist = [
    {
        'name' : "Ida Maria - Oh My God",
        'src' : "01 Oh My God.m4a",
        'codec' : 'mp4'
    },
    {
        'name' : "Miley Cyrus - Wrecking Ball",
        'src' : "06 Wrecking Ball.mp3",
        'codec' : 'mpeg'
    }
];

var ii = 0;

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.forward').click(function(){
        ii++;
        audio.unload();
        audio.urls = mp3_folder + playlist[ii].src;
        audio.load();
        audio.play();
    });
});
```

You will probably want to move the ii variable outside as well or you will have the same issue.